# Using WebDeploy for ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, build, web, publish, webdeploy

I am contemplating idea of using WebDeploy for deploying ASP.net websites. I am going through various articles but most of those are about deploying ASP.Net Web Application and not website.

When I right-click on Web Application project, I get lot of options to configure through WebDeploy but same is not in the case of Website.

I am sure WebDeploy can be used to deploy websites but I am confused about where to start. Do I have to use WebDeploy command line API's through MSBuild? What is it? Can someone please let me know the standard procedure?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using VS 2010 or VS 2012?  If so, you can install the latest VS updates (VS 2012.2 ASP.NET update or the latest Windows Azure SDK), and then you have all the same options for web site projects as you have for web application projects.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx and http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/introduction

Comment: Hi, I am using VS2010. The first link you sent did help. I needed to install "Visual Studio Web Publish Update". All looks good now.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just wrote a second article about packaging Websites using WebDeploy.

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/12/15/package-asp-net-website-not-app-in-a-ci-build/

The quick summary is you can use msdeploy.exe to package a website from within a custom cs.proj file and integrate it into a CI process.